# How to extract USGS gauges information with Web scraping functions in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to extract some simple information for this site:

https://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/inventory/?site_no=14091500

I want to get the value of Drainage area on this website, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

I have no idea how to realize this intention, because of the complex of website structure knowledge.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thank you.
I will read it. 
It is necessary for me to get familiar with the rules of this website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to do any complex web-scraping. the USGS has a nifty package called `dataRetrieval`.

```
library(dataRetrieval)
site <- readNWISsite(14091500)
site$drain_area_va
```

That code will give you the drainage area. There are lots of other attributes you can get as well. Check them all out here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataRetrieval/dataRetrieval.pdf

Comment: This is awesome.
What a great answer and package.
Thanks.

Comment: No problem. You can also use the package to get gauging data, water quality data, etc. Its a very useful package.

Comment: Absolutely yes. 
I spent a couple of days to deal with the dataset from this website. 
Now I can handle these data easily. 
Endless Thanks.